# Will Google Analytics treat url parameter as part of URL?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to incorporate my own parameters as part of url. (e.g. #student=DD&start=Date1&end=Date2). However, I am cerncerning about if I add my part to the url, will it mess up my google analytics tracking? Basically, now my url is something like -- `MywebsiteUrl?userID=AAA#student=DD&start=Date1&end=Date2&utm_source=CC...`.

What url Google analytics will track? is my website url -- `MywebsiteUrl`, or ``MywebsiteUrl?userID=AAA#student=DD&start=Date1&end=Date2`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics will treat query parameters as part of the URL. However it will not treat `#student=DD&start=Date1&end=Date2` as having query paramaters. As far as (native) Javascript and the GA tracking code is concerned the URL ends after the fragment identifier (`#`).

So your complete example

```
MywebsiteUrl?userID=AAA#student=DD&start=Date1&end=Date2&utm_source=CC
```

you will get `MywebsiteUrl?userID=AAA`. If the userID parameter contains personally identifiable information you need to remove it to conform to Google's terms of service. You can use a filter or the exclude parameters-box in the view settings.

Comment: Hmm, if `#` is the ending point, does it mean that we couldn't record  the afterwards url part like --`&utm_source=CC.`? That's the parameter we mark our link. We really want to record it.

Comment: @HaoyuChen, I suggest you pass in virtual urls (as optional parameter to you ga send pageview calls) which you can format to your liking.

Comment: What's virtual url? Is it defined in GA? How can I use it? Could you give me some doc about it? Thanks!

Comment: You can pass in an arbitrary string that is used instead of the url displayed in the browser. Google documents this in their instructions for single page applications: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications